# Navbar only changes menus after clearing caches?

Tags: html, wordpress, caching, browser-cache

I have added these codes in navbar that changes the menus if the user is logged in or out

[See the navbar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNbrn.png)

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="./index.php">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="./view-blogs">View blogs</a></li>
  <li><a href="./earning-policies">Earning policies</a></li>
  <li><a href="./index.php">Support</a></li>


  <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>

  <li><a href="./wp-admin" class="login_topBtn">DASHBOARD</a></li>
  <li><a href="./wp-login.php?action=logout" class="register_topBtn">LOG OUT</a></li>


  <?php } else { ?>
  <li><a href="./wp-login.php" class="login_topBtn">LOGIN</a></li>
  <li><a href="./wp-login.php?action=register" class="register_topBtn">REGISTER</a></li>
  <?php } ?>

</ul>
```

The navbar doesn't change and keeps giving "Dashboard" and "Logout" buttons when i log myself out from Wordpress, this problem only fixes when I clear cache by pressing Ctrl + F5. Any solution to remove this cache problem permanently will be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you update login status of user every time they access the website?

Comment: I dont know how to do that, please tell